# Merge two armatures into one

Tags: armature, bones

I want to merge two similar armatures, that have same named bones in them

And when I merge armatures with Ctrl+J, bones don't merge, the same named bones were like that: "head" and "head.001", "head.002"

So, can I make it so that when I merge armatures, their bones also merge? Or is there other combinations, add-ons?

Or if I do it by myself, is there hotkeys or ways to merge two or more bones into one, without loosing weights, groups and parents?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What should happen after merging? Lets say boneA is at (0, 0, 0) and boneB is at (1, 1, 1); are you looking for a median position and orientation?

Comment: I want to merge same named bones. There is already boneA and boneB in same positions. I just want to merge them without losing it parameters, like: parented bones, weights and other groups.

Comment: If both bones have the same params (size, position, parents), what benefit does the merging process have? You could just merge geometries (the weights get merged) and assign the new geo to either of the armatures.

Comment: I have a human armature, with same body part bones (spine, hips, hands, legs), but with different head part bones, let's say that Armature1 has mouth bones, Armature2 has eye bones, Armature3 has cheek bones and etc. And all Armatures (1, 2, 3) have same body part bones, so I want to merge that various face part bones. And when I merge this 3 Armatures, the face bones were correct, but body bones was not, they are like "spine", "spine.001", "spine 002" and etc. So I want same named and positioned bones are merging into one bone.

Hope I managed to explain.

Comment: If that's the case, I would personally just remove the duplicates manually before from Arm3 and Arm2, then join them with Arm1.

Comment: there just over 600 bones, that should be renamed, so, it would be preferable to find a lighter option.

Comment: [This code](http://pasteall.org/1063832/python) may get you started. It remove duplicate bones from selected armatures (relativ to the active armature). It doesn't solve the problem of parenting or constraints though. Maybe you can edit some content of the comments into the question.